# MySQL: GET_LOCK limits and issues

Tags: mysql, locking

I a need a database level synchronization. For this I'm using GET_LOCK('prefix.some_id', 0).
At some moment GET_LOCK returns 1 for same key in different scripts on different hosts. What could be the problem? I need lots of those locks, 5-7k approximately.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bug #1118 Allow multiple concurrent locks with GET_LOCK()](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1118)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This bug is resolved in "MySQL Server 5.7.5, GET_LOCK() now allows to acquire several locks and doesn't release currently held user locks." -- Details in the same URL

Answer (score 7):

MySQL 5.7.5 and MariaDB 10.0.2 both support your use case now.

For MySQL see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locking-functions.html

For MariaDB see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/functions-and-operators/miscellaneous-functions/get_lock/

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock), you cannot hold more than one lock per connection via `GET_LOCK()` (emphasis added):

> If you have a lock obtained with GET_LOCK(), it is released when you execute RELEASE_LOCK(), **execute a new GET_LOCK()**, or your connection terminates (either normally or abnormally)

As Daniel posted, there is a [feature request](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1118) for this functionality, but it was filed in 2003 with no activity.

Depending on your use-case, you may be able to use MySQL's table or row-level locking to achieve what you want.

Comment: Update "Before 5.7.5, only a single simultaneous lock can be acquired and GET_LOCK() releases any existing lock." "In MySQL 5.7.5, ....Multiple simultaneous locks can be acquired".

Comment: @SamSippe Single simultaneous locks per connection can be acquired right ? Question clearly mentioned for different script and different hosts means different connection so this shouldn't have happened.